# VHDL parse error, unexpected DIV

Tags: vhdl

I'm asked to show the number of the most pressed number on a keypad 
this is the only error that shows

> ERROR:HDLParsers:164 - "D:/project/compartor.vhd" Line 37. parse
>   error, unexpected DIV

and this is line 37

```
if Int_Key = i  then
```

What does the error means? And how can I solve it?

and this is the full code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
---------------------------------------------------------------

entity compartor is
port
(
Key_out : in  std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
clk,rst: in std_logic;
Winner: out std_logic_vector (3 downto 0)    
);
end compartor;

architecture Behavioral of compartor is

Type Data is array (0 to 15) of integer;
Signal Counters:Data:=(others=>0);
Signal Max:integer;
Signal MaxPlace:integer;
Signal INT_Key:integer:=conv_integer(Key_out);


begin


process (clk,rst)
begin
if (rst='1') then
Winner<= (others=>'0');

elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then


  for i in 0 to 15 loop
     if Int_Key = i  then   
       Counters(i)<= Counters(i)+1;
     end if;
  end loop;

Max <= Counters(0);
MaxPlace <= 0;
    for i in 0 to 15 loop 
      if (Counters(i) > Max) then 
        Max <= Counters(i);
    MaxPlace <= i;
      end if;
    end loop;

end if;
end process;
Winner<= conv_std_logic_vector (MaxPlace,4);

end Behavioral;
```

Comment: The problem can't be reproduced from your code.  From your comment to the answer *Second, there was a note that I wrote in the code and removed it here hence the error. I used "//my notes" instead of "--notes".*, the first forward slash responsible for the parser error (DIV) on the removed line using an incorrect comment delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't see reason for that specific error message, but there are other issues with the code.

The `Winners` output port is driven both in the process, and outside the process, thus having multiple drives, which the Xilinx synthesis tool won't accept.

The assign to `INT_Key` in the declaration like:

```
Signal INT_Key:integer:=conv_integer(Key_out);
```

gives `INT_Key` and initial value based on the `Key_out` input port, which is probably not what you want, so consider instead doing:

```
Signal INT_Key:integer;
...
INT_Key <= conv_integer(Key_out);
```

Note, that signal assignment with `<=` in the process does not make the new value available until next time the process is executed, for example in the case of `Max <= Counters(0)`.  It may be what you want, but it is a common pitfall for VHDL starters.

Even through VHDL is case insensitive, it is bad style using different casing for the same identifier, like you used `INT_Key` and `Int_Key`.

Consider indenting your code to follow the control structure; that will save you lots of debugging and make the code much more readable.

And a final suggestion, make a test bench for the design, and simulate before trying to make it run on hardware.  Doing this extra simulation effort will actually make you finish earlier, not later.

Comment: First of all thanks for the reply. Second, there was a note that I wrote in the code and removed it here hence the error. I used "//my notes" instead of "--notes".

Comment: The code now works fine after placing the Int_key inside the process and giving result of Winners before ending the process. Thank you